# Magento 2 override shipping estimate controller form

Tags: magento2, estimate

I want to override controller which is called when we estimate shipping and tax.

and controller ajax url is:

http://10.10.10.88/postnetship/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/92617c8345b9702c2928cde0cef5ff76/estimate-shipping-methods

[image]

How  I can add my custom code to estimate shipping cost.

Comment: which purpose you want to overide this controller?

Comment: I have created custom shipping method and I need to add dynamic shipping cost.